# Where are the LaTeX binaries stored in linux? (latexDraw configuration)

Tags: graphics, paths

I just made a nice diagram in latexDraw but the problem I am having is that I cannot seem to add mathematical symbols.

I am guessing it is because of the configuration so I looked to see if I could fix it (see image).

I am running xubuntu linux if that helps.

[image: latexdraw preferences in linux]

In the preferences is asks me for the location of the binaries and I don't know where they are. Is it the .sty files they mean or something else? will this even fix it?

Update:

I followed the advice below and typed in

```
>which latex
```

It returned

```
 >/usr/bin/latex
```

So I stuck that in but I am still having problems. Also when I clicked on the folder it went to `usr/bin` but the only folder it could see inside was `X11`

Example of problem and code produced.

```
    % Generated with LaTeXDraw 2.0.8
% Sun Jan 27 00:59:07 GMT 2013
% \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
% \usepackage{epsfig}
% \usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
% \usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
% User packages:
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\begin{figure}[p]
\scalebox{1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-2.9492188)(18.655624,2.9392188)
\psframe[linewidth=0.04,dimen=outer](4.42,1.5292188)(3.52,0.24921875)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](7.5,0.8492187)(4.38,0.8492187)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.56,-1.3107812)(3.56,-2.470781)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.76,-1.7107812)(3.76,-2.190781)
\pscircle[linewidth=0.04,dimen=outer](7.52,-1.0707812){0.74}
\pscircle[linewidth=0.04,dimen=outer](0.74,1.1892188){0.74}
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](7.5,0.82921875)(7.5,-0.35078126)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.76,-1.9507812)(7.54,-1.9507812)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](2.04,0.88921875)(2.04,-1.9307814)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.74,0.24921875)(3.74,-0.55078125)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.96,1.5292188)(3.94,1.8092188)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](7.52,-1.8107812)(7.52,-1.9707812)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.52,0.88921875)(2.02,0.88921875)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.56,-1.9307814)(2.04,-1.9307814)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.75785375,0.42925632)(0.74214625,-0.5908188)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.74,1.9092188)(0.74,2.6492188)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.9400015,2.6294518)(0.72,2.6692188)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](1.9,-0.53078127)(0.72,-0.55078125)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(3.9606247,0.86921877){\small Ge }
\usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}
\rput(0.720625,1.1542188){\Large V}
\usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}
\rput(7.5406246,-1.0657812){\Large A}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(5.2698436,-2.5907812){\small DC Voltage Supply}
\psframe[linewidth=0.04,dimen=outer](2.2,-0.8907812)(1.9,-1.6307813)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm,arrowsize=0.05291667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.4]{->}(1.52,-0.81078124)(2.62,-1.7907811)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.32,-2.0507812)(3.32,-2.2907813)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.46,-2.1707811)(3.18,-2.1707811)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](4.22,-2.1907814)(3.94,-2.1907814)
\psframe[linewidth=0.04,dimen=outer](12.68,1.3892188)(11.78,0.10921875)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](15.8,0.74921876)(12.68,0.74921876)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](11.8,-1.8107812)(11.8,-2.4107811)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](12.0,-1.5907812)(11.98,-2.7307813)
\pscircle[linewidth=0.04,dimen=outer](15.78,-1.2107812){0.74}
\pscircle[linewidth=0.04,dimen=outer](9.0,1.0492188){0.74}
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](15.78,0.74921876)(15.78,-0.53078127)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](12.02,-2.0907812)(15.8,-2.0907812)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](10.3,0.74921876)(10.3,-2.0707812)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](12.22,0.08921875)(12.22,-0.7107813)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](15.78,-1.9507812)(15.78,-2.1107812)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](11.78,0.74921876)(10.28,0.74921876)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](11.82,-2.0707812)(10.3,-2.0707812)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](9.0,0.32921875)(8.98,-0.69078124)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](9.0,1.7492187)(9.0,2.4892187)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](12.28,2.4892187)(8.98,2.5092187)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](10.16,-0.67078125)(8.96,-0.69078124)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(12.220625,0.7292187){\small Ge }
\usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}
\rput(9.000625,0.9742187){\Large V}
\usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}
\rput(15.800625,-1.2057812){\Large A}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(13.529843,-2.7307813){\small DC Voltage Supply}
\psframe[linewidth=0.04,dimen=outer](10.46,-1.0307813)(10.16,-1.7707813)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm,arrowsize=0.05291667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.4]{->}(9.78,-0.9507812)(10.88,-1.9307811)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](11.58,-2.2307813)(11.58,-2.4707813)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](11.72,-2.3507812)(11.44,-2.3507812)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](12.52,-2.3707812)(12.24,-2.3707812)
\psline[linewidth=0.06cm,arrowsize=0.05291667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.4]{<-}(16.54,1.1087693)(17.407234,1.6736897)
\psline[linewidth=0.06cm,arrowsize=0.05291667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.4]{<-}(17.42,2.9092188)(17.421688,1.700552)
\psline[linewidth=0.06cm,arrowsize=0.05291667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.4]{->}(17.421688,1.6736897)(18.6,1.6492188)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(18.525469,1.4342188){x}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(17.673437,2.7942188){z}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(16.747812,1.0342188){y}
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](7.5,0.82921875)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](7.54,-1.9707812)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](15.82,-2.1107812)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](15.8,0.70921874)
\psarc[linewidth=0.04](2.04,-0.53078127){0.18}{0.0}{180.0}
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.74,-0.49078125)(2.22,-0.49078125)
\psarc[linewidth=0.04](10.3,-0.69078124){0.18}{0.0}{180.0}
\rput{87.473885}(5.7319264,-2.1319435){\psarc[linewidth=0.04](3.98,1.9292188){0.18}{0.0}{180.0}}
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.96,2.6692188)(3.96,2.1292188)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](12.22,1.3692187)(12.2,1.6492188)
\rput{87.473885}(13.507985,-10.498628){\psarc[linewidth=0.04](12.24,1.8092188){0.18}{0.0}{180.0}}
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](12.26,2.5092187)(12.26,1.9692187)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](10.5,-0.69078124)(12.22,-0.7107813)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](11.22,0.74921876)(11.22,1.8892188)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](11.2,1.8492187)(12.96,1.8492187)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](12.96,1.8292187)(12.96,0.7292187)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](4.74,1.9492188)(4.74,0.8492187)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.04,0.82921875)(3.04,1.9692187)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](3.0,1.9292188)(4.76,1.9292188)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(5.2814064,1.3942188){\psframebox*[framesep=0, boxsep=false,fillcolor=white] {$\Omega$}}
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](3.08,0.87921876)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](4.76,0.89921874)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](11.24,0.75921875)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](13.02,0.7992188)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(13.541407,1.4142188){\psframebox*[framesep=0, boxsep=false,fillcolor=white] {$\Omega$}}
\end{pspicture} 
}
\end{figure}
```

The `userpackages` bit is my contribution that I put in.
[image: the picture produced. The math package is being ignored]

Comment: Try `/usr/bin`. Or some folder on `/usr/local/texlive`.

Comment: it will mean the executable latex itself (and bibtex) etc, if you can run latex on the command line then it's in your path somewhere  `which latex` would tell you on my system it says `which latex
/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-cygwin/latex` so it would want `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-cygwin` but your path will be different

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks. Can you read my edit and let me know what you make of it please? Thanks.

Comment: I guess I'll pass sorry I have never used that system and don't have a linux machine here at present, you wouldn't expect many or any subfolders of /usr/bin other than X11 so that sounds normal.

Comment: yeah I think it found it. I found a place to add packages now too but it doesn't seem to make a different. I will add the picture

Comment: Also out of interest is /usr/bin/ where I am meant to install latex packages ? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: no almost certainly you are using texlive and it's all in something like /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist...  with symbolic links in /usr/bin to the executables, but modern tex distributions come with package managers (either tlmgr or the one used for your linux distribution) that automatically install latex packages where needed. There are several questions on this site about linux installation

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Linux, you do not have to set the path of the LaTeX binaries. This field mainly is for Windows users and custom configurations.

If you have compilation issues, it comes from LaTeX packages that you must include in your drawing. For that, you can either go into the preferences in the LaTeX tab to set the packages to use for all the drawings, or with latexdraw 2.0.8 go into the properties of the current drawing and set the packages to use for the current drawing. 
With latexdraw 3.x to set the packages to use for a drawing, you must click on the text button and a tool bar will appear at the bottom of the application. In the toolbar you can set the packages.